# Netlogo code for a model

Tags: netlogo

I want to create a very simple model of how a rummor spreads. I just started learning the NetLogo code and I would appriciate some help building the code or an example of a similar code.

Comment: Please read the [asking help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on how to frame questions on this site. In general, this forum is to be used for solving specific problems that you run into rather than an open-ended request for help. Otherwise, try looking through the NetLogo model library, which has a variety of model/code examples, for some inspiration.

Comment: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/community/Social%20influence%20in%20networks

Comment: NetLogo's Models Library, which comes with the program, includes a model called "Rumor Mill".

Comment: Do you want to build for a specific network?